# How to check modifications in GIT repository during period of time

Tags: git

How can I see all modifications user has made on repository during a particular time period (e.g a month, or since 1st day of current month)? I need to see whole files before his modification and after his modification (not only the diff).

Comment: I think it would be nice to look in repository with GitExtensions https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command to show all the commit logs history since the beginning in a branch

```
git log
```

after execting this command, you will find that each commit or log has commit id and Author with its date, copy the commit ID and right this command:

```
git show COMMIT_ID
```

The command above will show the commit details by the author assigned to this commit id

Another solution it to write something like this:

```
git whatchanged --since '04/14/2013' --until '05/22/2014'
```

The code above it like git log however with filters (range)

Comment: you can use the two commands in one, by saying:

    git whatchanged --since '04/14/2013' --until '05/22/2014' -p 

the above code is like tell git diff with range

Comment: Also: `git log --since=2014-10-20 --before=2014-10-27 --oneline`. The since and before options can be passed to various commands that want a range of commits.

Comment: I think it is a very good solution to show each commit id with its message, however it won't show so much details about each commit like the author and the commit date

Comment: I tried similar commands, but I did not figure out how to get whole file before modification, and after it. Morover I would like to have info per user.

Comment: Note that `git log` provides the same functionality as `git whatchanged`. `whatchanged` is mostly kept for historical reasons.